# Properties of a JAR file inside a WAR file not being picked up at run time?

Tags: gradle, gradlew

I'm a DevOps guy not a dev per-se so I may not phrase this post correctly, but here goes.

We use Gradle to build. I know this is a REALLY old version, but that's what we have. Updating the version will probably open a different can of worms.

```
$ ./gradlew --version

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 2.9
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2015-11-17 07:02:17 UTC
Build number: none
Revision:     b463d7980c40d44c4657dc80025275b84a29e31f

Groovy:       2.4.4
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on December 23 2013
JVM:          1.8.0_181 (Oracle Corporation 25.181-b13)
OS:           Mac OS X 10.13.6 x86_64
```

I have 2 modules, module-core and module-app, and module-app depends on module-core so I have this in my module-app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies {
  compile project('module-core')
  ...
}
```

module-core has the following properties file

```
module-core/src/main/resources/application-production.properties
```

and has the following key/value pairs

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

module-app has the following properties file, and is **EMPTY**. Note the slight difference in path - it has a "config" subdirectory in path that module-core does NOT!

```
module-app/src/main/resources/config/application-production.properties
```

module-app then has the following XML file which dictates (from what devs tell me) how the key/value pairs in each properties file are aggregated

```
module-app/src/main/resources/admin-properties.xml
```

and has the following stanza

```
<beans profile="production">
    <context:property-placeholder
            location="classpath:application.properties,classpath:config/application.properties,classpath:application-production.properties,classpath:config/application-production.properties"
            ignore-unresolvable="true"/>
</beans>
```

After I do a

```
$ ./gradlew clean build -x test
```

The module-app.war has in it a module-core.jar file

```
$ cd /path/to/module-app.war
$ tar -xvf module-app.war
$ cat ./WEB-INF/lib
$ tar -xvf module-core.jar
$ cat application-production.properties
```

and it has the correct values.

```
key1=value1
key2=value2
```

However, when we run our module-app.war application via tomcat, these values are NOT being picked up, as seen in the logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Just FYI gradle 2.9 is really old 4.10.2 is the current gradle version.

Comment: I know, but i'm new in the company so I haven't asked questions on why we're using a really old Gradle

Comment: I did try Gradle v4.10.2, and I was right - a BIG can of worms!

Comment: The longer you keep it, to bigger the worms are getting ;)

Comment: If I understood it well it all works correctly. You have two properties files and both are included into the final war, correct? On in the war itself and second in the jar included into the war? This is how it works. Also `context:property-placeholder` is resolved at runtime, not during build. In just points the spring framework from which files it should read the properties and inject them into classes. It has nothing to resolving the properties at build time.

Comment: @Opal, yes we use v2.9 in our monolith (legacy) code but are moving to v4.10.x as we move some code into microservices. For your second comment, I updated the post - like I said I'm a DevOps guy not a dev per-se.

Comment: This sounds like a Spring issue rather than a Gradle one. Surely the log output from Spring Framework says whether it's finding those files or not?